# Anime: boy spawns down monsters, including a floating eyeball, is saved by an adult from drowning when diving to look for a boat

Tags: story-identification, anime

When I was younger like 6-7, I used to watch an anime.

There was a guy, he looked more realistic than other animes. I remember something that he could spawn down monsters (I remember one monster which was like a floating eye something like that). I also remember in later episodes that they would bunch up as a group, the guy, a girl kinda the same age as him with both an older guy and a woman.

I remember tiny parts of some episodes like one they would be running from the bad guys on roof tops or something like that.

I also remember that in one episode, the two guy were going on a dive to a boat wreck, the younger one passes out and is about to drown but the older one saves him and gets him back up.

I used to watch the anime on a French channel on TV, it was dubbed in French.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's [*Huntik*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1696969/), an American-Italian cartoon aired between 2009 and 2012.

From left to right, meet Sophie, Lok, Dante and Zhalia (who's not yet a woman but can be perceived as such).

[image: Cartoon still]

**I remember something that he could spawn down monsters (I remember one monster which was like a floating eye something like that).**

The four main characters are "Seekers"; Seekers can summon creatures known as the Titans with the help of several amulets. [Here's a sheet with all Titans and their summoning amulets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dgbz.jpg), and the floating eyeball you remember is the Red Searcher:

[image: Weird-looking red eyeball with wings]

**In one episode, the two guy were going on a dive to a boat wreck, the younger one passes out and is about to drown but the older one saves him and gets him back up.**

That's episode 10, "The Treasures of the Argonauts", and the clip of Dante saving Lok is on YouTube:

---

Found by habit, as I had identified that [five times before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5D+huntik+user%3A98028). When searching for "people summon creatures"-like animes, I now first check whether *Huntik* matches.